# Is there a numpy.where() equivalent for row-wise operations?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to find the index of first occurence of some condition row-wise, such that it returns a vector. I would need something like an `axis=0` condition in `np.where` or the `pylab` `find` function, but that is not implemented.

To clarify, imagine I have the following matrix:

```
d=np.array([[0,  1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0,0,0,1]])
```

I want the first occurrence of `d==1` row wise.

The result should be `[1, 1, 0, 3]`, but I don't see how to do this with `np.where` or any other function efficiently.

Comment: I don't understand how an axis on `np.where` would help you. If you just had a 1D vector, how would you use `where` to solve this problem? If you can explain that, we can probably explain how to extend it.

Comment: if I had a 1D vector I would use where(d==1)[0] or find(d==1)[1]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think what you're looking for here isn't `where`, which will return you an array of elements from one of two different arrays depending on the condition, but [`argmax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html#numpy.argmax), which returns you the index of the maximum value—or, for a 2D array, the indices of the maximum value of each row or column.

But you don't want the maximum value, you want the values that are `1`, right? Well, `d==1` is an array of booleans, and `True` is greater than `False`, so:

```
In [43]: np.argmax(d==1, axis=1)
Out[43]: array([1, 1, 0, 3])
```