# Apply numpy 'where' along one of axes

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array like that:

```
array = np.array([
        [True, False],
        [True, False],
        [True, False],
        [True, True],
        ])
```

I would like to find the last occurance of `True` for each row of the array.
If it was 1d array I would do it in this way:

```
np.where(array)[0][-1]
```

How do I do something similar in 2D? Kind of like:

```
np.where(array, axis = 1)[0][:,-1]
```

but there is no `axis` argument in `np.where`.

Comment: This answer is almost a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25228146/3381305 — if you don't mind getting `0` for a `True` in the zeroth column **and** when there is no `True` in that row at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [an older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25228146/3381305) but didn't like that it returns `0` for both a `True` in the first position, and for a row of `False`.

So here's a way to solve that problem, if it's important to you:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[False, False, False],  # -1
                [False, False, True],   #  2
                [True, False, False],   #  0
                [True, False, True],    #  2
                [True, True, False],    #  1
                [True, True, True],     #  2
               ])

# Make an adustment for no Trues at all.
adj = np.sum(arr, axis=1) == 0

# Get the position and adjust.
x = np.argmax(np.cumsum(arr, axis=1), axis=1) - adj

# Compare to expected result:
assert np.all(x == np.array([-1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2]))

print(x)
```

Gives `[-1  2  0  2  1  2]`.

Comment: That's a great answer. I thought about method DYZ mentioned in the other answer, but I didn't really like all these array flipping operations and wanted more elegant solution.
np.cumsum is a great idea, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Since `True` is greater than `False`, find the position of the largest element in each row. Unfortunately, `argmax` finds the first largest element, not the last one. So, reverse the array sideways, find the first `True` *from the end*, and recalculate the indexes:

```
(array.shape[1] - 1) - array[:, ::-1].argmax(axis=1)
# array([0, 0, 0, 1])
```

The method fails if there are no `True` values in a row. You can check if that's the case by dividing by `array.max(axis=1)`. A row with no `True`s will have its last `True` at the infinity :)

```
array[0, 0] = False
((array.shape[1] - 1) - array[:, ::-1].argmax(axis=1)) / array.max(axis=1)
#array([inf,  0.,  0.,  1.])
```