# Is there a numpy.where() equivalent along axis?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to make maximum intensity projections of image stacks. This means that the brightest (highest value) point of the layers should be saved for each pixel.
I have a for loop that loops through every pixel of my images, but this is slow. I intend to optimize my code by using numpy functions that apply to the whole array.

I start with an example image stack of 3x3 pixels, 4 layers:

```
testLayer1 = [
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0]
]
testLayer2 = [
    [1,1,1],
    [1,1,1],
    [1,1,1]
]
testLayer3 = [
    [0,1,2],
    [3,4,5],
    [6,7,8]
]
testLayer4 = [
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,10]
]
testStack = np.array([testLayer1,testLayer2,testLayer3,testLayer4])
```

In the code below I show my first method and the output for an example image stack. This is the slow method, but returns the desired output.

```
def MakeMaxIntProj(stack):
    maxIntProj = np.zeros((2,stack.shape[1],stack.shape[2]))

    # Loop through all the pixels in the image
    for i in range(stack.shape[1]):
        for j in range(stack.shape[2]):
            maxIntProj[0,i,j] = np.max(stack[:,i,j]) # Find the maximum intensity value of pixel i,j and save it
            maxIntProj[1,i,j] = np.where(stack[:,i,j] == maxIntProj[0,i,j])[0][0] # Find the corresponding layer and save its number
    
    return maxIntProj
```

The output for the example image is

```
In [1]: MakeMaxIntProj(testStack)
Out[1]: array([[[ 1.,  1.,  2.],
                [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
                [ 6.,  7., 10.]],

               [[ 1.,  1.,  2.],
                [ 2.,  2.,  2.],
                [ 2.,  2.,  3.]]])
```

Then for the new method I have the following (partial) solution:

```
def MakeMaxIntProj(stack):
    maxIntProj = np.zeros((2,stack.shape[1],stack.shape[2]))
    
    maxIntProj[0,:,:] = np.max(stack,axis=0)
    maxIntProj[1,:,:] = 0# Try to find an np.where equivalent here
    
    return maxIntProj
```

With result:

```
In [2]: MakeMaxIntProj(testStack)
Out[2]: array([[[ 1.,  1.,  2.],
                [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
                [ 6.,  7., 10.]],

               [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
                [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
                [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

This is somewhat similar to [jacob's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228023/is-there-a-numpy-where-equivalent-for-row-wise-operations), but the solution to his question only works for a more limited case.
So what can I do to make the second part of the new output correct, while still avoiding for loops?

Comment: `np.argmax(testStack, axis=0)` works for you? It returns the indexes along axis 0 where the maximum is located. Here is the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html). You can also use it as a method: `testStack.argmax(axis=0)`.

Comment: Yes, that does exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! I could even use it to index the original array to find the maximum values, so the maxima don't need to be calculated twice.